# Microsoft Graph API Beta: Subscribe to Event Notifications of another user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I created an app on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

with the following Application Permissions:

`Calendars.Read (Admin Only)` `Calendars.ReadWrite (Admin Only)` `User.Read.All (Admin Only)`

**Admin Consent**

Admin consent was then successfully granted via this URL

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/strixtechnology.onmicrosoft.com/adminconsent?client_id=bbb35336-faee-4c10-84b4-34136634db41&state=1234&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdashmeetings.com%2Fmicrosoft%2Foauth
```

**Get access token**

An access token was then obtained from

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

with headers

```
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and body with key-value pairs

```
grant_type=client_credentials
client_id=bbb35336-faee-4c10-84b4-34136634db41
client_secret=xxx
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

This returns an access token.

**Subscribe to notifications**

Using that access token, I then try to subscribe to the events on a certain resource mailbox:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions
```

with headers

```
Content-Type=application/json
Authorization=Bearer <access_token_here>
```

and body

```
{
   "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
   "notificationUrl": "https://dashmeetings.com/microsoft/notify",
   "resource": "users/mahogany@strixtechnology.com/events",
   "expirationDateTime":"2017-12-01T11:00:00.0000000Z",
   "clientState":"1234"
}
```

This returns a `401 Unauthorized` with

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Unauthorized; Reason: Unauthorized]",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "98ce5e5e-1ce4-4417-8c35-456a3cc0e696",
            "date": "2017-11-30T10:59:28"
        }
    }
}
```

This question seems similar to [“Resource not found for the segment” using Graph subscription beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147060/resource-not-found-for-the-segment-using-graph-subscription-beta?rq=1), but I follow the same steps without any luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin consent URL had to be

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client‌​_id=bbb35336-faee-4c‌​10-84b4-34136634db41‌​&state=1234&redirect‌​_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fd‌​ashmeetings.com%2Fmi‌​crosoft%2Foauth
```

and the access token address:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/to‌​ken`

Comment: Hi! What is the <tenant_id> here?