# Microsoft Graph API not returning refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-oauth

I created an app on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

with the following Application Permissions:

`Calendars.Read (Admin Only)` `Calendars.ReadWrite (Admin Only)` `User.Read.All (Admin Only)`

The following is the only flow that has worked for me to be able to subscribe to notifications of another user, on another tenant, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572013/microsoft-graph-api-beta-subscribe-to-event-notifications-of-another-user)

**Admin Consent**

Admin consent was then successfully granted via this URL

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=bbb35336-faee-4c10-84b4-34136634db41&state=1234&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdashmeetings.com%2Fmicrosoft%2Foauth
```

**Get access token**

An access token was then obtained from

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

with headers

```
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

with `{tenant}` the value of `tenant` returned in the callback url,

and body with key-value pairs

```
grant_type=client_credentials
client_id=bbb35336-faee-4c10-84b4-34136634db41
client_secret=xxx
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

This returns an access token, but not a refresh token.

I think this might be because `offline_access` isn't requested.

How can I get a refresh token?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're partially correct, you will only receive a `refresh_token` if you request the `offline_access` scope *and* you are using the `authorization_code` grant flow.

Refresh tokens are not available when using the `implicit` grant and are unnecessary when using the `client_credentials` grant. When using `client_credentials` there isn't a user authenticated and therefore there isn't a need to "refresh" a token since you can simply request a new token when needed.

Answer (score 0):

A `refresh_token` isn't needed.

As long as the admin consent has not been revoked, a new `access_token` can be requested when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `refresh_token` which is a long-term token you can append the `offline_access` into your scopes.

Alternativally, you can also use the `basic` on scope as it cotains the `offline_access`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had not used the offline_access scope in the authorization request.

```
    GET /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client_id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access
&state=12345
```